# Install4j - unistalling linux application

Tags: install4j

I'm making multiplatform(win and linux without GUI) installer for my application - using install4j.
Install4j creates application.sh installation file. When I run this sh file - my application is installed on linux machine. But whats the correct way how to uninstall my application? No uninstaller.sh was created. Should I run application.sh with some additions arguments? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The uninstaller is created wherever you specify it. On Installer->Screens & Actions, select the "Uninstaller" and check its "Executable name" and "Executable directory" properties.